# Android SDK emulator on IBM ThinkPad Core Duo T5870 2gb ram

Tags: android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [slow android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

I am on the specified laptop and the emulator seems to take forever. Are there any recommended settings I could try to expect increased performance?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer mark it as "accepted". Furthermore it would be nice if you tried to ask questions in a more generic way. That way more people would be able to find it.

Even more, im pretty sure this has been answered before so try searching next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up boot time of the image:

> AVD Manager -> Edit [AVD] -> Snapshot Enabled